# Detect specific device (with or without screen) for Google Assistant in DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I am creating an app for Google Assistant using DialogFlow, without any external web server.

Some answers redirect to a YouTube video (using a basic card). I would like to handle devices which can not play YT videos (like Google Home/Nest) by returning a different answer (like "please use the assistant on your phone to play the video") or maybe prevent the full intent to be available on a device without a screen.

Is there a way to restrict an intent for a specific type of device only ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below method to check the screen capabilities.

```
const conv = agent.conv();
const hasScreen = conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT');
```

You can even check other capabilities as well. check the doc [here](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/surface-capabilities#asdk_node_has_capability).

Comment: Thanks for the link ! I made it work within dialogflow interface (without any node server) by adding `actions_capability_screen_output` to the "context" field of my intent.